One of the inputs is slower than the rest of them
One the inputs works really slow compared to rest of them, the problem is it is not a specific input but the 3-rd one from the bottom, so is I switch the order the 3rd one from the bottom will still be slow, does anybody have any idea why? I've never encountered anything like this before and seems silly. I am using Expo, react-native-papers. However I removed all of my states and it is not the state that is slowing down or anything, just inputing text into the input box.
Thanks in advance
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper'

const CreateAccount = () => {
return (
     <SafeAreaView>
         <View>
             <Text>Create Account</Text>
             <View>
                 <TextInput label='Phone'  />
                 <TextInput label='Email'  />
                 <TextInput label='First Name'  />
                 <TextInput label='Last Name'  />
                 <TextInput label='Password' secureTextEntry />
                 <TextInput label='Confirm Password' secureTextEntry />
             </View>
         </View>
     </SafeAreaView>
   )
 }

export default CreateAccount

I've tried to remove states put logs and see if anything else gets triggered, however even when I removed all states and added just the inputs it is still not working properly

UPDATE !!!!: if I remove the secureTextEntry from the password and confirm password then all the rest work fine, once I add it back the input that renders right before the password will be slow, it is still not solving any issue, it is just something I tested.

By the way I suggest using NativeBase or Material UI instead

It is a problem when I add secureTextEntry, when is true, somehow the above one is lagging, if I remove it, everything works fine, I've seen this issue being reported before but no solution has been provided, does anyone knows how to fix this?
